# How do I split treat a string (not a file) as a line in a CSV file and parse the string?

Tags: ruby, string, csv, parsing

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  Given a particular delimiter character, how can I treat a string as a line in a CSV file and use the delimiter to split that line into an array of tokens?  All the examples online that I have found, for instance

```
table = FasterCSV.read(result_file.to_file.path, { :headers => true, :col_sep => "\t", :skip_blanks => true })
```

require reading in an entire file.  It seems wasteful to write my line to a file, read the file back, and then delete the temporary file I've created.  Also using the "split" function doesn't seem safe if the delimiter is a comma because CSV files will sometimes have commas in the data (in which case quotes surround the data).

An example of such a string might be

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

If the delimiter passed in is "\t", the result would be ["a,b,c,d,e"] but if the delimiter used were a ",", the result woudl be ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

Comment: Not sure why you're using FasterCSV when the built-in CSV module is equivalent.

Comment: As @tadman said, FasterCSV _is_ Ruby's built-in CSV so just use CSV for clarity and simplicity. Then I'd recommend reading the examples in [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) as they cover this very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have arbitrary string data you want to parse as CSV you can just use `parse`. No need for a temporary file:

```
require 'csv'

commas = %Q[a,b,"c,d"]

CSV.parse(commas)
# => [["a", "b", "c,d"]]

tabs = %Q[a\tb\t"c\td"]

CSV.parse(tabs, col_sep: "\t")
# => [["a", "b", "c\td"]]
```

The `col_sep` option allows you to specify what separator is used.

Answer (score 4):

FasterCSV has long since been [adopted as the CSV module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) in the Ruby standard library. Just `require "csv"`.

A very brief glance at the CSV docs reveals the [`CSV.parse_line`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse_line) method.

```
require "csv"
CSV.parse_line("a,b,c,d,e")
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

`CSV.parse` takes all of [the same options as `CSV.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) et al, so you can pass the `col_sep: "\t"` option to use tabs as the separator instead:

```
CSV.parse_line("a,b,c,d,e", col_sep: "\t")
# => ["a,b,c,d,e"]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/FGft/1

Comment: In your example, 'CSV.parse_line("a,b,c,d,e")', how does it know what the token separator is, or does it just assume it is always a comma?

Comment: It defaults to a comma ("CSV" stands for "comma-separated values"). Like I said, it takes [the same options](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) as `CSV.new`, so you can pass the `col_sep: "\t"` option to use tabs instead. I've updated my answer with a second example.